# Cited sources are displayed as identical

Tags: bibliographies

I have following problem: I cited two source both by Kubernetes (left), but they appear as the same cited source (right). shouldnt one of them be (Kubernetes, 2022c)?

[image]

this is my literature.bib:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Since you're not showing any code, it's impossible to know what you're doing and what could trigger the problem. Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Also, avoid screenshots and type the code so that people can copy-paste it for testing purposes. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase hi, I have about 100+ cited sources. this is the first time this error happend. for example I have multiple microsoft sources, but they actually count up from 2022a to 2022e. this kubernetes source is the only one I have this problem with.

Comment: We can only help you if you tell us more about your bibliography and citation setup. We need to know which bib/cite-related packages you load (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, ...) and which bibliography style you use. This is best done in a small example document that starts with `\documentclass` contains the relevant bits of your preamble and has a short body (`\begin{document}...\end{document}`) containing just enough text and citations to reproduce the problem. We do not need to see your 100+ cited sources. It is enough to share a reduced document that reproduces what you get at the moment.

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots: The code is harder to read (and may be an accessibility issue for people relying on screen readers). Plus if people want to test your code or improve it, they have to re-type all of it. Code should be copied-and-pasted as text directly into the question and marked up as code with the `{}` button.

Comment: Nevermind found the problem... one author was {Kubernetes} instead of {{Kubernetes}}... not sure why that is a problem but fixing it solved my issue....